# How do I remove solid colour background behind text in vscode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to remove the solid colour background behind all the folder names in vscode. [This picture shows the terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2ljF.png)

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Linux, you can completely remove colors:

1. `cd /`
2. `vim ~/.bashrc`
3. Click 'i' for insert.
4. Scroll to `force_color_prompt=yes`, and comment it out like this `#force_color_prompt=yes`
5. Hit Esc. Then Colon. Type "wq" and enter to save.

Or, remove solid background only:

1. `dircolors -p | sed 's/;42/;01/' > ~/.dircolors`
   Then update the terminal so changes take effect:
2. `source ~/.bashrc`

Done!